# Extend Conversation model in Mailboxer gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mailboxer

I want to extend Conversation model, so that i can use an association with it. I have done it  by creating a file named 'conversation.rb' in app/models directory in this way:

```
Mailboxer::Conversation.class_eval do
  belongs_to :device, class_name: "Device", foreign_key: 'device_id'
end
```

I have also added a column named 'device_id' in conversations table.

But when i tries:

```
Conversation.last.device
```

It say:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `device' for #<Mailboxer::Conversation:0x007fe83e6ae7c0>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `app/models/conversation.rb` won't be loaded if `Mailboxer::Conversation` is called. I made this work for me by moving your code to `config/initializers/mailboxer.rb`. Additionally, I wrapped the code in `Rails.application.config.to_prepare` since in development mode this code have to be re-executed on reload (see [Monkey patching Devise (or any Rails gem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118657/monkey-patching-devise-or-any-rails-gem)):

```
Mailboxer.setup do |config|
  [...]
end

Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  Mailboxer::Conversation.class_eval do
    belongs_to :device
  end
end
```

This way, something like `current_user.mailbox.conversations.first.device` should be possible.

Comment: Thanks, lacco :) I'm using Rails 5.0.2 and it works fine without wrapping the code in `Rails.application.config.to_prepare` block.

Answer (score 1):

You can try inherit from it

```
class Conversation < Mailboxer::Conversation
  belongs_to :device, class_name: "Device", foreign_key: 'device_id'
end
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that this won't work out of the box since Mailboxer will still use the ```Mailboxer::Conversation``` class.  If this is the preferred solution, something like ```current_user.mailbox.conversations.first.becomes(::Conversation)``` might help.